# Laravel raw query: Removing chars from string | How can it be improved?

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

I am using a global search bar that accepts user input as strings. However, I want to emit special typing characters. Think of dots, commas, ETC. You can see my current database check below (since it is Ajax based):

```
public function scopeWhereName($query, $queryString) {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($queryString) {
        $query->where(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, ' ', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, '.', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, ',', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, '!', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, '?', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, ':', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, '-', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, '@', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, '#', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, '&', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%')
        ->orWhere(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, '/', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%');
    });
}
```

My question, as stated in the title, is **If it is possible that the queries above can be made into a better query, so it is performance lighter and easier to read.**

Comment: I think you should prepare the data before using php

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I do that in my controller:

(Code provided in hastebin due to being too large to fit into a comment) https://hastebin.com/lanifudefe.php

Comment: You can simplify your controller code: `$string = str_replace([' ', '.', ',', ...], '', $request->get('query'));`

Comment: This question qould be better placed at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Thank you; A colleague already found that out for me.

Comment: @ggdx Did not knew that existed; Bookmarked it straight away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the query creation:

```php
$chars = [' ', '.', ',', ...];
foreach($chars as $char) {
    $query->orWhere(\DB::raw("REPLACE(name, '$char', '')"), 'LIKE', '%' . $queryString . '%')
}
```

If you do a lot of searching, you should maybe create a separate column that stores the name without special characters.

Comment: I do get an error whilst running your code:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '') LIKE ? and REPLACE(name, :, '') LIKE ? and REPLACE(name, -, '') LIKE ? and ' at line 1

**Code itself**
https://hastebin.com/exuwokuqir.php

Comment: I forgot the quotes around `$char`: Use `'$char'`.

Comment: Thank you for your eagle eye; I assumed since the array items were strings it would see $char itself as a string.